# Amazon CloudWatch log agent ignoring first character of log lines

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

If I add a batch of `n` test records to my log file, the awslogs agent is erroneously ignoring the first character of the first line of the batch of rows that I add. This is fully reproducible. So if I use `vi` to append the following test log lines:

```
2017-06-16 15:20:01,123 this line will not get correctly parsed. first character in date string will be skipped.
2017-06-16 15:21:23,456 this will get parsed. 1
2017-06-16 15:22:23,456 this will get parsed. 2
2017-06-16 15:23:23,456 this will get parsed. 3
2017-06-16 15:24:23,456 this will get parsed. 4
2017-06-16 15:25:23,456 this will get parsed. 5
2017-06-16 15:26:23,456 this will get parsed. 6
2017-06-16 15:27:23,456 this will get parsed. 7
```

The leading `2` in the first row gets omitted by the log agent. In the CloudWatch Logs web console, the event shows up as `017-06-16 15:20:01,123 this line will...`, the datetime string does not get successfully parsed, and the log event must use the timestamp of the previous log.

In the common scenario where I add log events to the file one at a time, the first letter of each line is ignored and the timestamp strings do not get correctly parsed. If I append multiple lines in `vi` before hitting `:w` save, only the first line experiences this problem and the other lines in the batch get ingested correctly.

I created the log file (as a test) with `touch` and have only added lines manually with `vi` so I don't think this is a file encoding problem.

I'm using a mostly standard default configuration.

My CloudWatch Agent Config File:

```
[general]
state_file = /var/awslogs/state/agent-state

[/var/log/myapp/app.log]
file = /var/log/myapp/app.log
log_group_name = MyAppLogGroup
log_stream_name = MyAppLogStream
datetime_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f
```

Then I download the latest setup script from `https://s3.amazonaws.com//aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py`

And run `sudo ./awslogs-agent-setup.py -n -r us-west-2 -c cloudwatch_logs.config`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the

```
initial_position = start_of_file
```

option in your config file explicitly, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Tried that. Reran awslogs-agent-setup.py, verified that the new config setting was in `/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf`, restarted the awslogs service, added a new batch of test records, and it didn't help. There is no change in behavior.